# cant understand tcl regexp pattern matching, usage of ^ and +

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a simple TCL regexp matching,

```
regexp {^[^,]+} $n id
```

that works on strings like "1,last".
it strips the text and returns only the number, but I cant understand how it works
I though that the "^" sign means "ignore"/negate

I cant see how it identifies the number hope you can help me...thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` can have two meanings.

Outside of a character class, it's an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) meaning "start of string" (or start of line, depending on current options).

Within a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), it negates its contents. `[^abc]` matches a character that is neither an `a`, a `b`, nor a `c`.

So in your example, the regex only matches from the start of the string/line, thereby allowing `[^,]+` to match the `1` and preventing it from matching `last`.

Comment: hm, ok - so the regexp here works like that - 1.looks for start of a string 2. return everything untill the ","/comma ?
(Thanks for the speedy reply!!!)